# How do I write dialogue separated with 'said' in the middle?

Tags: dialogue, punctuation

I'm studying for a test and don't know which one of the two following bits of dialogue is correct, and I haven't been able to find the answer online since I don't know what it is called.

1. "Hello," John says, "it's a beautiful day!"
2. "Hello", John says, "it's a beautiful day!"

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you follow the American punctuation. The exclamation mark is the emphasis John puts on his words, therefore it's integral to the quoted matter, so should be inside the punctuation that ends the quote. I also notice that you use double quotation marks, which is the American way. The Brits use a single quotation mark. Start American, finish American.

Comment: Adding to the above, there are 2 sentences: **"Hello," John says. "It's a beautiful day!"*

Comment: Yes, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct.  Generally the first is done in American English while the latter is done in British English.  Note that the difference is where punctuation is placed with respect to the closing quotation mark.  British will place it after closing quotes, while Americans place it before.

There is no correct way to do it, but it should be consistent.  Sentence 2 is incorrect because the Exclamation point is within the closing quote.

Comment: Ah, I'm not exactly used to British english. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I'm not saying I own a huge collection of British books (or English books at all) but I've never seen anything like that in a British book, or really a published book in any language. Here's a random sentence from my copy of Father Brown stories by G. K. Chesterton, published by Wordsworth Editions in 1992: *'Reverend sir,' cried Angus, standing still, 'are you raving mad, or am I?'* Note that the comma comes before the quotation mark (which is of the single kind because this is a British book published in England, UK).

Answer (score 0):

In **British English** the comma before "John says" goes inside the quotation marks if there is punctuation in the quoted speech and outside if there isn't:

> Bob likes cheese. → ‘Bob’, I said, ‘likes cheese.’
> Bob, do you like cheese? → ‘Bob,’ I asked, ‘do you like cheese?’

(Source: [University of Oxford Style Guide](https://www.ox.ac.uk/sites/files/oxford/media_wysiwyg/University%20of%20Oxford%20Style%20Guide.pdf), p. 16)

In **Amercian English** the comma always goes inside the quotation:

> Bob likes cheese. → “Bob,” I said, “likes cheese.”

(Source: [Modern Language Association of America Style Center](https://style.mla.org/punctuation-and-quotation-marks/))

As the MLA explains, in British English the convention is *logical*, in American English the convention is *typographical*.